# 'flash-messages' is not a known element angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a weird problem 
I use angular2-flash-messages in my Angular 6 project.
I already installed it via npm, added it to app.module.ts as module like this

```
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
```

added it to the modules section

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
DemoMaterialModule,
FormsModule,
FlexLayoutModule,
HttpClientModule,
PerfectScrollbarModule,
SharedModule,
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'angular-auth-firebase'),
AngularFireDatabaseModule,
AngularFireAuthModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
FlashMessagesModule.forRoot()
```

and I added the service to my login.component.ts

```
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
```

but when I add the

```
<flash-messages></flash-messages>
```

to login.component.html 
an error fired in the error console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'flash-messages' is not a known element:
1. If 'flash-messages' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'flash-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<flash-messages></flash-messages>
<div class="login-register"  style="background-image:url(assets/ima"): ng:///AuthenticationModule/LoginComponent.html@0:0
Error: Template parse errors:
'flash-messages' is not a known element:
1. If 'flash-messages' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'flash-messages' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<flash-messages></flash-messages>
<div class="login-register"  style="background-image:url(assets/ima"): ng:///AuthenticationModule/LoginComponent.html@0:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22696)
    at compiler.js:22639
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22639)
    at compiler.js:22549
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22696)
    at compiler.js:22639
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22639)
    at compiler.js:22549
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4053)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

but if I add

```
<flash-messages></flash-messages>
```

to the main app component (app.component.html) like this

```
<router-outlet>
  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
</router-outlet>
```

Everything is working fine.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is login.component.ts in a different module than app.component.ts?

Comment: yes it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the `FlashMessagesModule` for each module, in which you want to use it. In some cases you need to import `.forChild()` when you have already imported it, e.g. `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`, but not for the `FlashMessagesModule`.